# Sort wp_query results by parent page title

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array alphabetically based on the parent page title. I have a query that retrieves all pages with a specific page template. When outputting the retrieved pages I need to sort them by the title of the parent page and not the title of the retrieved page itself.

**What I have so far:**

```
$opnamePages = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'orderby'           => 'title',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'meta_key'          => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value'        => 'templates/dienst-sub-opname-page.php'
));

if($opnamePages->have_posts()){
    echo "<div class='subNavigationDropdown'>";
        echo "<div class='dropdown'>";
            while($opnamePages->have_posts()){
                $opnamePages->the_post();
                $parentPage = wp_get_post_parent_id(get_the_ID());

                    echo "<a href='".get_permalink()."' title='Ga naar ".get_the_title()."'>".get_the_title($parentPage)."</a>";
            }
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
wp_reset_postdata();
```

}

Comment: I don't think that is possible, directly via WP_query options. You will probably have to fetch all posts as an array first, and then sort that.

Comment: You will have to loop through your results and create an array where either key or value is the title and the other is the post id. Sort that array. Then loop through that array showing your output